# prevent user to write local characters

Tags: html, input

I want to prevent user to write local characters (croatian - ĆČĐŠŽ) inside a input

```
<input type='text' pattern='[A-Z0-9]'>
```

but id doesn't work - local characters are written by typing.

And what is then the purpose of `pattern` attribute ?

Any help?

Comment: FWIW, "local characters" doesn't mean anything. Perhaps you mean non-ASCII?

Comment: @HoàngĐăng, what is then the purpose of `pattern` attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

The `pattern` attribute work for `form`. It will check when the form is being submitted.
For validation when user typing, you need to make function for `onChange` event.

Update form @Anarion
`onKeyUp/onKeyPress/onKeyDown` because in some browsers `onChange` happens only on focus-out.

Comment: Better - `onkeyup`/`onkeypress`/`onkeydown`. In some browsers 'change' happens only on focus-out.

Comment: and what should I write on that `onKeyUp...` to get only alphanumeric input ?

Comment: @bonaca get the text from the input then remove the invalid characters by `var validString = invalidString.replace(/[your_regex]/g, "");`. It is the same for other event.

Comment: @HoàngĐăng, but I don't want to `remove` already typed character, I need to `prevent` it to be typed at all.

Comment: What is the purpose of prevent it to be typed, using above solution it make the invalid characters remove immediately.